# Input HTML code into form input

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on an angular app which has a blog feature. The form input textarea takes in multiple paragraphs but displays them in one big paragraph. For example, if I enter

> "this is para1.
>
> this is para2."

it shows as

> "this is para1. this is para 2."

I want to know if I can view the paragraphs separately, specially if I can input HTML code. For example , if I enter into the form input "para1 LINK", I want it to appear as "para1 LINK" where LINK is clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this using Text Area. You can use WYSIWYG Text Editor where you can preserve html tags.

Check this angular plugin

http://textangular.com/